# converting hybrid cg/hlsl shaders to glsl es

Tags: hlsl, cg, glsles, hlsl2glsl

I am looking for a tool that can convert cg/hlsl hybrid shaders to glsl es shaders. I have tried hlsl2glsl which doesnt understand the keyword 'extern' although it is a viable hlsl keyword and have looked to cgc but have found no documentation on how to compile for glsl es.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Old question, I know, but I'll offer this answer, anyway.

I came across this while [legally] wanting to appropriate some fine Unity-targeted CG shader code ;-)

**Take a look at the CG-shader-to-GLSL-shader Python conversion script '[cg2glsl.py](https://github.com/libretro/RetroArch/blob/master/tools/cg2glsl.py)' on Github (it requires the `cgc` command found within the [`nvidia-cg-toolkit`](https://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit) package, supported on most OSes.**

Its usage is, briefly, outlined in '[converting from cg shaders](https://github.com/libretro/RetroArch/wiki/GLSL-shaders#converting-from-cg-shaders)'

Quoting from Tomaka17's CG-to-GLSL-related blog post ['Turning Cg into GLSL, and then using the code'](http://blog.tomaka17.com/2010/09/turning-cg-into-glsl-and-then-using-the-code)

> Cg is a shading language developed by nVidia. Basically you write all
>   your shaders in Cg....Cg will in fact compile your code into the
>   API-specific language.

In [Tomaka17's](http://blog.tomaka17.com/2010/09/turning-cg-into-glsl-and-then-using-the-code) example, he intercept's nVidia CG-library calls using C++ to extract the compiled GLSL code, which I would suggest is conceptually the same as what [cg2glsl.py](https://github.com/libretro/RetroArch/blob/master/tools/cg2glsl.py) would be doing (although without having to compile the code by way of its Python usage).

Answer (score 2):

cgc filename -profile glslv/glslf

But you have to add presecion for glsl es, cg compiler doesn't this